# For how long does Luke train with Yoda?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-empire-strikes-back, luke-skywalker, yoda

I have always been surprised how confident Luke seemed to be when trying to rescue Han Solo from Jabba's palace.

It is fair to assume that training with Yoda boosted his Jedi skills. My understanding is that all that he trains with Yoda is what we see on screen, since in The Return of the Jedi he asks Yoda about what Vader told him in Bespin, a question Luke not refrain to ask when he had the chance (so there is no "off camera" training with Yoda between episodes 5 and 6).

I know that it is impossible to know how much training with Yoda improved Luke's abilities, but maybe it is possible to know for how long he trained with him?

My recollection from watching The Empire Strikes Back is that there is no good or reliable way of measuring the time our heroes spend either imprisoned in Bespin or in Dagobah, but maybe I missed something or there are other sources that can answer the question of **how long does Luke Skywalker train with Yoda**?